# select rows that has particular number in Col D

Tags: excel, vba

In my Column D i have numbers. Normally most of the rows for Col D will have single number eg 2 or 12 or 22 and so on. However on some occasion it will have two or more numbers eg 2, 4,12.  The numbers in the cell are separated by commas.

Example:

```
       Col D
Row1    1
Row2    4
Row3    2,12
Row4    11,1
Row5    2,1
Row6    3
Row7    21
Row8    1,11,15
Row9    10,1,9
Row10   1,16
```

How can I select
all the rows that has in Col D the number 1
ie in the above example it would select row1,row4,row5,row8,row9 and row10

Many thks

Comment: Can add another column into your table? With formula like this `=IF(OR(D1=1,RIGHT(D1,2)=",1",LEFT(D1,2)="1,"),TRUE,FALSE)` and then filter on True only?

Comment: @Aneta the formula you used wouldn't catch Row9 as having the number 1... Maybe `=IF(OR(D2=1,RIGHT(D2,2)=",1",LEFT(D2,2)="1,",MID(D2,3,3)=",1,"),TRUE,FALSE)` will do it.

Comment: On a somewhat related sidenote: What is your endgoal here (other than selecting the cells)? It's generally not a good idea to be using `Select` in `excel-vba`

Comment: @Xabier You are absolutely right. There can be a problem with `mid` function, what if there are more than three number, I guess `find` would solve it

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
Sub SelectRows()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range, rw As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test") ' change to your specific sheetname

        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            LookIn:=xlValues).Row

        For Each rw In .Columns("D").Rows 
            If InStr(1, rw.Value, "1") > 0 Then
                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = rw
                Else
                    Set rng = Union(rng, rw)
                End If
            End If
            If rw.Row = lastRow Then Exit For
        Next rw
    End With

    rng.Select

End Sub
```

**Edit #1**
This improved code has no false positives as the earlier version:

```
Sub SelectRows()

    Dim addBool As Boolean
    Dim lastRow As Long, lenTempStr As Long
    Dim rng As Range, rw As Range
    Dim tempStr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test") ' change to your specific sheetname

        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            LookIn:=xlValues).Row

        For Each rw In .Columns("D").Rows 
            addBool = False
            tempStr = Replace(rw.Value, Chr(32), vbNullString)
            lenTempStr = Len(tempStr)

            If InStr(1, tempStr, "1") > 0 Then
                If lenTempStr = 1 Then
                    addBool = True
                ElseIf InStr(1, tempStr, ",1,") > 0 Then
                    addBool = True
                ElseIf Left(tempStr, 2) = "1," Then
                    addBool = True
                ElseIf Right(tempStr, 2) = ",1" Then
                    addBool = True
                End If

                If addBool Then
                    If rng Is Nothing Then
                        Set rng = rw
                    Else
                        Set rng = Union(rng, rw)
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            If rw.Row = lastRow Then Exit For
        Next rw
    End With

    rng.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also Find the value in Row 7 as it contains the digit 1 in the number 21?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Maybe_A()
Dim c As Range, i As Long, a As String
a = ""
    For Each c In Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)
        For i = LBound(Split(c, ",")) To UBound(Split(c, ","))
            If Trim(Split(c, ",")(i)) = "1" Then
                If a = "" Then
                    a = c.Address(0, 0)
                        Else
                    a = a & "," & c.Address
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next c
Range(a).EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thks to all of you. Much appreciated. Below is the code which I came up with your help. Not sure how good it is and if it would do, although it seems to working. I had not seen select case true being used before!

```
Sub FindN()
    Dim rC As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim sFind As String, fC1 As String, fC2 As String, fC3 As String, fC4 As String
    sFind = [d3].Value 'type the numeral to find in cell D3
    'find criteria - i think there are four outcomes
    fC1 = sFind: fC2 = sFind & ",*": fC3 = "*," & sFind & ",*": fC4 = "*," & sFind
    Rng = Range("d4:d14")

    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    For Each rC In Rng
        Select Case True
            Case rC.Value = Val(fC1)   'for numeric 1
                rC.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case rC.Value Like fC2
                rC.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case rC.Value Like fC3
                rC.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case rC.Value Like fC4
                rC.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case Else
                rC.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```